# they ________ early on Sundays

Tags: grammar

Options:
A) haven't got up 
B) aren't getting up
C) don't get

I'm really confused about this question that came in a test. I appreciate any help with this one.

Comment: Are you sure C isn't actually "don't get up"? That would be the natural choice for this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This is a poor question on the part of the test author, because either A) or B) could be correct, depending on context. Choice C) seems to be missing a final word. Either "up" or  "out"would make C) correct and so might other  words.

Comment: for choice A) does present perfect apply here ? that's why i'm a bit confused

Comment: A) doesn't sound correct to me, an American, because I would only say "they haven't **gotten** up early"!

Comment: Yes, for A) it's more brittish than american. Guess it's B) ?

Comment: Brits wouldn't just say 'We haven't got up early on Sundays' on its own. We'd have to add something like 'today', 'since we converted to the Wesleyans', 'ever in our lives'.